# What is the precipitate of this reaction of magnesium?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, precipitation

$\ce{MgSO4}$, on reaction with $\ce{NH4OH}$ and $\ce{Na2HPO4}$, forms a white crystalline precipitate.
Identify the precipitate.

My approach: I guess the white crystalline precipitate is $\ce{Mg(OH)2}$, since it is white and insoluble in water.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, if we look at the possible compounds that can form here:

Mg(OH)<sub>2</sub> = Insoluble,
MgHPO<sub>4</sub> = Soluble,
(NH<sub>4</sub>)<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub> = Soluble,
(NH<sub>4</sub>)<sub>2</sub>HPO<sub>4</sub> = Soluble,
Na<sub>2</sub>SO<sub>4</sub> = Soluble,
NaOH = Soluble

So, it appears your guess is correct.

Answer (score 8):

With $\ce{(NH4)2HPO4}$, $\ce{Mg^2+}$ forms a white, crystalline precipitate of [magnesium ammonium phosphate hexahydrate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struvite):

$$\ce{Mg^2+ + HPO4^2- + NH4^+ + OH- + 5H2O \rightleftharpoons Mg(NH4)PO4 \cdot 6H2O\downarrow}$$

This is a very sensitive test for $\ce{Mg^2+}$; however, calcium, strontium, barium and other heavy metal ions also form precipitates of phosphates under these conditions. $\ce{Mg(NH4)PO4 \cdot 6H2O}$ can be distinguished by the form of its crystals when they are examined under a microscope. It forms rhombic crystals with prismatic shape, and is less microcrystalline than other earth alkali metal phosphates (sources: [1](http://books.google.de/books?id=CLCdzlwv3f8C&pg=PA86&lpg=PA86&dq=magnesium%20ammonium%20phosphate%20hexahydrate%20%2b%20qualitative%20test%20for%20magnesium&source=bl&ots=DuKIya4G0O&sig=e7nSA1oG382uladhClVw9USgqqI&hl=de&sa=X&ei=bJ94U_W2CZOK4gSliYGoCg&ved=0CDwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=magnesium%20ammonium%20phosphate%20hexahydrate%20%2b%20qualitative%20test%20for%20magnesium&f=false), [2](http://books.google.de/books/about/Lehrbuch_der_analytischen_und_pr%C3%A4parati.html?hl=de&id=nJkuAAAACAAJ)).